# Opengl, 2d stationary shapes, in a 3d scene with a moving camera

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I have a 3d scene drawn out in Opengl, the camera is allowed to pan around the scene. How do I go about adding 2d shapes to the window that will be unaffected by the camera moving?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally this is done by drawing in two steps. Assuming that you would like the 2D shapes to always be "on top" of scene like a GUI, I would render your 3D scene, then use [glOrtho2D](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/gluOrtho2D.3G.html) and draw your shapes. You'll probably want to also disable depth testing. Be sure to set back up for your 3D each frame.

Answer (score 2):

After drawing the scene, you can set the camera matrix to an orthographic view, and draw the 2D overlay.

If the outline of your 2d overlay is free-form in any way, you can use an alpha mask to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another toolkit and embed the OpenGL frame. [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) is popular and portable.